# How to change global variable in Solaris?

Tags: global-variables, solaris

I've tried to change global variable DSQUERY in Solaris with this command:

```
setenv DSQUERY "SYBSERVER"
```

but it wasn't persisted. When I entered again in the machine the value was set to the older one.

How can I persist this change?

Comment: In Unix those are called "environment variables", not global - using that term should help you find many more docs in searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put this line in your profile file. This file is read when you start a shell, and allows you to set-up some specific settings.
The filename depends on the shell you use and how you connect (with a direct connexion or with a su for example).

It seems you use csh, so you will have to change $HOME/.cshrc and.or $HOME/.login files.
Add your SetEnv command to .cshrc and .login file will do the job.

Comment: If you use tcsh, you will have to change .tcshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in the user profile files, depending on the shell being used (.login, .cshrc, .bashrc, etc) so that when you log in again, it's executed automatically. There are global versions of those files under /etc for some shells, in case you want that to be applied to all users.

Rgds,
Daniel